# Horizontal and vertical scrolling in a UITableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make a lineup for a festival. You can see what I want to achieve below here.
[image]

You can scroll in every direction ,horizontal - vertical and from left to right corner (don't know the proper word in english).If you scroll in one section ever other section should scroll with it.

My question is know how can you achieve this? I'm searching for days to get this working but don't find a good solution...

Comment: do you want to horizontally scroll only the UITableViewCell, ie a single row at a time or the whole UITableview

Answer (score 5):

The row in the UITableView doesn't scrolls itself inside the UITableView. one solution Is to use an UIScrollView and then inside add the UITableView. This UIScrollView will have the same size that your UITableView have now, but the UIScrollView contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width.

[image]

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, x, x, x) style:...]

[scrollView addSubview:tableView];

// Set the size of your table to be the size of it's contents 
// (since the outer scroll view will handle the scrolling).
CGRect tableFrame = tableView.frame;
tableFrame.size.height = tableView.contentSize.height;
tableFrame.size.width = tableView.contentSize.width; // if you would allow horiz scrolling
tableView.frame = tableFrame;

// Set the content size of your scroll view to be the content size of your 
// table view + whatever else you have in the scroll view.
// For the purposes of this example, I'm assuming the table view is in there alone.
scrollView.contentSize = tableView.contentSize;
```

Comment: This will work but will cause the table load all all rows, so it's not suitable for long lists. Just make the frame of the tableview equal to  the bounds of the scrollview. The scrollview will do the horizontal scrolling (that's why it's contentSize.width is wider than the screen) and the tableview will do the vertical scrolling (depending on the number of rows).

Comment: have u found any better solution pls share it

Comment: @Bonnie Can you please add the code for swift

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding with UITableView scrolling you can follow this two links

[horizontally table scrolling](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1)

[vertically table scrolling](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2)

i hope it helps you for better understanding and make familiar with UITableViewDelegate. Thanks