# both horizontal and vertical tableview using swift

Tags: swift, xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hupru.jpg)

I need to implement a vertical and horizontal tableview and fixed header, the tableview need to move both directions. Any idea? using swift

Comment: The wording is too generic. It would be great to know more details about what exactly you want to implement (layout/wireframe).

Comment: I need to implement a list view in iOS, but the problem I'm facing is the tableview need to move both directions horizontal and vertical with sticky headers.

Comment: Yes, you've already told more or less the same thing in your question. However, this short description can be interpreted multiple ways. The best would be to add a picture of a wireframe with desired result.

Comment: I don't think we need to go personal, my question is just a generic request for any other person who has time to help you with building layout. But as one option, could something like this help: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-add-uicollectionview-inside-uitableviewcell-using-swift/ ?

Answer (score 2):

For vertical scrolling you can use UITablevew and for horizontal scrolling you need to use UICollectionView. Please have a look at this article, they have implemented exactly what you want.

[Horizontal and vertical scrolling in a UITableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436454/horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-in-a-uitableview)